# apple.local Dock[255]: ECFileOperationRevealURL failed with -43

Tags: macos, dock

Cmd+click on any file can reveal them in Finder but now takes no effect.

I reviewed the console log and found following error:

```
May  2 00:14:12 apple.local Dock[255]: ECFileOperationRevealURL(file://localhost/Users/suyejun/Downloads/code/) failed with -43
```

I installed PathFinder and uninstalled it after I found this error. But the error still exits.

I'm sure that before installing PathFinder, the functionality is ok.

How can I fix this? Thank you.

OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.3)

Comment: Could you verify if installing back Path Finder solves the problem? There's a checkbox under Settings -> General tab on that toggles using it as the default file browser. There's any chance you left it checked before uninstalling Path Finder?

Comment: Installed it back and the option is not checked.

Comment: What happens when you paste `file://localhost/Users/suyejun/Downloads/code/` in the location bar of a Safari window and hit return?  What happens when you use the Finder's Go -> Go to Folder... and paste `/Users/suyejun/Downloads/code/` and click `Go`?  Are you sure the folder still exists with that name?

Comment: @OldPro Yes, the folder is exist. I just clicked it with cmd+click and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that PathFinder isn't actually the culprit here.  I downloaded and extracted (although didn't install) PathFinder, and searched for *ECFile*, and found no matches:

```
Mitsu:Contents ashley$ pwd
/Users/ashley/Downloads/Path Finder.app/Contents
Mitsu:Contents ashley$ find . -type f -exec grep ECFile {} \;
Mitsu:Contents ashley$
```

I suspect *ECFileOperationRevealURL* is actually the name for some code within the Dock application itself.  I say that because I found the text *ECFileOperation* in a [2007 webpage](https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/74709-time-to-bring-back-the-real-stacks/) where people are discussing features added to the Dock in a beta release of OS X 10.5.  I can't verify this easily on 10.8, though, as `/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock` is now an [apple-protected (encrypted) binary](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103161737/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter7/binaryprotection/), which can't be meaningfully searched with `grep` as above.

So, some suggestions:

1. Just to check I have the right end of the stick: you are saying that if you <kbd>cmd</kbd>-click an icon in the Dock, nothing happens, except that you get an entry in `console.log`?
2. Is this true for both applications (to the left of the Dock separator line) and folders (to the right)?  (Assuming you have the Dock on the bottom of the screen.)
3. If you create a new user account (for testing only), does the problem persist there?
4. If the problem goes away in the new user account, try moving `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` to another location temporarily (say your Desktop), then restart.  This should reset your Dock setup.  If this fix doesn't work, you can always put the file back.  If it does work, I'd suggest setting up the Dock again from this fresh start.

Comment: Thank you so much. I moved `com.apple.dock.plist` and restart, it goes well now.